# regular expression, only contain lower case or uppercase characters or both, for username validation

Tags: java, regex

To validate my string, I need the string only contains lowercase or uppercase or both cases mixed characters from A(a) to Z(z), and string length should be in the range from 6 to 12 characters long. What's the regular expression for this restrain?

Comment: I find that this site is very helpful for learning/understanding regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info

Comment: @Owen - +1 for the great resource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
[A-Za-z]{6,12}
```

However, it will match an instance of your criteria inside of the input string, so you can add the `^` and `$` anchors to ensure your entire input string conforms to your criteria.

```
^[A-Za-z]{6,12}$
```

Comment: You should add anchors `^[A-Za-z]{6,12}$`

Comment: @M42. I remembered that on the way to work. Thanks.

Comment: @M42 if the test is String.match() (or Matcher.match() for that matter), then anchors are not needed.

Answer (score 6):

You could use this regular expression:

```
^[\p{Lu}\p{Ll}\p{Lt}]{6,12}$
```

if you didn't want to penalize people for being named François, María, or Fuß.

Of course, what a string's length is in Java is less than perfectly clear, especially here, since the `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes only deal with lengths in code points (logical Unicode characters), not in the length of the string in Java's built-in but *very* oxymoronically named `char` units (physical 16-bit pieces of UTF-16).

That means that strings with surrogates will appears to have a different length from the standpoint of the regex engine than from many other Java classes.

The regex engine has it correct, BTW.

Comment: Great answer (+1). There's much more than ascii out there!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[a-zA-Z]{6,12}
```

Comment: You should add anchors `^[A-Za-z]{6,12}$`